# How to create a new not null column with existing data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am creating a new column in a table which is a uuid/guid.

add_column :users, :uuid, :string, null: false

I am setting the uuid using:

```
SecureRandom.uuid
```

The migration fails because the existing data doesn't have any value.

How can I set the value for each user with a new uuid during this migration?

Comment: You have neglected to mention what database software you are using....MySQL? MS SQL? PostGre?

Comment: @mrunion I'm using postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options when adding a not null column:

1. Provide a DB default
2. Add a nullable column, update all the data, change the column to non nullable.

Depending on what DB you're using it might or might not allow you to set an expression as the default value.

Since you've mentioned you're using Postgres, you can read more [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122623/default-value-for-uuid-column-in-postgres)
Rails syntax for providing the default will be

```
default: -> { 'uuid_generate_v1()' }
```